# How to check if a child class override a virtual method of parent class in c++

Tags: c++

I have a parent class `Parent`:

```c
class Parent
{
public:
  virtual void foo(){ printf("parent foo"); };
  virtual void do_something();
}
```

And two children `Child1` :

```
class Child1 : public Parent
{
public:
  virtual void foo(){ printf("child foo"); };
}
```

and `Child2` :

```
class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
  void bar();
}
```

As you see, `Child1` override the `foo()` method, while `Child2` don't override it.

So I want to know if there is some way to check it in `Parent::do_something()` like this:

```
Parent::do_something(){
  if (this->do_override_the_foo_method(){ // which is I want to implement
    printf("override foo");
  } else {
    print("not override foo");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this just for fun, or do you have an application in mind?  There is probably a more C++-like way of achieving whatever it is that you want to do.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth do you mean there is a way to do this? can you show me a example?

Comment: It's not clear to me this has any practical purpose, but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want to do something differently in do_something depending on the derived class why not just create a method in the derived class to do it? Or override do_something itself. Or perhaps rewrite to use some kind of double dispatch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: This may be a level of reflection C++ is incapable of.  Not sure if the vtable function would point to the same memory location.  As far as another way around this, perhaps you could use Strategy pattern.

Comment: @Montdidier Because I already have lots of existing code. If I do this in another method, I have to override it in all relevant classes. Anyhow I will try to find a easy way.